# Wso2 DSS Tenant Endpoint Url not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have created one tenant in Wso2 DSS. Login with Tenant Details and deployed one service. When i am testing it, the DSS Service is giving response as expected. But when i am trying to test that Service in restclient the endpoint url is not responding. Endpoint url looks like this http://Host:Port/services/t/tenantDomain/ServiceName/

This is the Error:-

```
[2015-06-10 10:47:18,900]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant 1
[2015-06-10 10:47:21,603]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: eKYCServices {mpszambia.com[1]}
[2015-06-10 10:47:22,113]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils} -  Loaded tenant mpszambia.com in 3595 ms
[2015-06-10 10:51:05,767] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.statistics.internal.ResponseTimeCalculator} -  wso2statistics.request.received.time is null in the IN MessageContext
```